# powershell - variable inside a string variable shall update even after it was declared

Tags: powershell

As you can see, the variable `$SQLRCNumberNew` is inside another variable `$SQLUpdateRC` which has been declared before `$SQLRCNumberNew` did.

When I am running the script `$SQLRCNumberNew` is empty, which makes sense because it is declared inside `$SQLUpdateRC` at the beginning.

What I want to ask if someone has an idea how I can update `$SQLRCNumberNew` even it is declared at the beginning.

I know I can just put the string Variable right below, but this is not what I am looking for.

Thanks for any help!

```
$RCFirstDigit = 0
$RCSecondDigit = 0

$PhoenixDBServer = "Servername"
$PhoenixDBName = "Databasename"
$ProductionDBServer = "Servername"
$ProductionDBName = "Databasename"

$SQLSelectRC = $("SELECT [Char_Value_01] FROM [dbo].[TABLENAME] WHERE [Keyword] = 'Version Number'")
$SQLUpdateRC = $("UPDATE TABLENAME set Char_Value_01 = '$SQLRCNumberNew' where Keyword = 'Version Number'")

Switch ($env:COMPUTERNAME) {
    $PhoenixDBServer {
        $Server = $PhoenixDBServer + "." + $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
        $Database = $PhoenixDBName
    }
    $ProductionDBServer {
        $Server = $ProductionDBServer + "." + $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
        $Database = $ProductionDBName
    }
    default {
        Write-Verbose "This script does not run on this computer"
        exit
    }
}

$SQLRCNumber = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Query $SQLSelectRC

[int]$RCFirstDigit = $SQLRCNumber.Char_Value_01.split(".")[1]
[int]$RCSecondDigit = $SQLRCNumber.Char_Value_01.split(".")[2]

$RCSecondDigit++

# put string back together with updated RC number
[string]$SQLRCNumberNew = $SQLRCNumber.Char_Value_01.Split(".")[0] + "." + $RCFirstDigit + "." + $RCSecondDigit

# Update RC Version on Database
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Query $SQLUpdateRC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear - this is not how PowerShell scripting works. When you assign data to your variables, at least when working with strings.

You could have a function inside your script file, that you could call and have it return the concatenated string.

```
Function StringBuilder {
Param ($Value)
"UPDATE TABLENAME set Char_Value_01 = '$Value' where Keyword = 'Version Number'"
}  


...
$SQLRCNumber = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Query $SQLSelectRC

$SQLUpdateRC = StringBuild $SQLRCNumber
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Query $SQLUpdateRC
...
```

Something like that should work. But I would say you should have a string format defined in the top and simply format when you need it.

```
$SQLUpdateRCBase = "UPDATE TABLENAME set Char_Value_01 = '{0}' where Keyword = 'Version Number'"

...
$SQLRCNumber = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Query $SQLSelectRC

$SQLUpdateRC = $SQLUpdateRCBase -f $SQLRCNumber
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Query $SQLUpdateRC
```

Comment: Awesome @Mötz, your second example was exactly what I was looking for. I tried already with string formatting (-f) but somehowe it didnt update, maybe because I hat the variable inside looking like this $("query '${0}'"

Comment: So did you fix it? "bla blac '${0}' bla blac" isn't the same as "bla blac '{0}' bla blac"

Comment: yes, i could fix it by using your ideas from your second code-block example. Thanks alot.
You have an example or ref. where it is explained why "bla blac '${0}' bla blac" isn't the same as "bla blac '{0}' bla blac"?

Comment: The $ sign is when you are working with variables. In a text string "This is a test: {0}" the {0} isn't a variable. {0} is a formatting index, that is used when you try to format strings.

You can read more about string formatting here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/11/understanding-powershell-and-basic-string-formatting/

Comment: And one more about string formatting https://hodgkins.io/the-ultimate-guide-to-powershell-string-formatting